# R: Argument is Missing, With No Default

Tags: r, panel, estimation, mle

I have  log likelihood function that I want to optimize with mle2 package in R.
In this code, B0 represent beta0, B1 represent beta1, and else.
First, I have panel data with 5908 people for 5 years,

```
data("HealthIns")
dat<- pdata.frame(HealthIns,index = c("id","year"))

y<-data.matrix(dat$mdu)
y[is.na(y)]=0
Y<-matrix(data=y,nrow=5908,ncol=5)

dat$ageclass<-ifelse(dat$age >=30,1,0)
x1<-data.matrix(dat$ageclass)
x1[is.na(x1)]=0
X1<-matrix(data=x1,nrow=5908,ncol=5)

dat$gender <-ifelse(dat$sex=="male",1,0)
x2<-data.matrix(dat$gender)
x2[is.na(x2)]=0
X2<-matrix(data=x2,nrow=5908,ncol=5)

x3<-data.matrix(dat$disease)
x3[is.na(x3)]=0
X3<-matrix(data=x3,nrow=5908,ncol=5)
```

Here's my (-log likelihood) function,

```
po.gam=function(B0,B1,B2,B3,A){
  
  {for (i in (1:5908)){
    for(t in (1:5)){
      lambda<-as.matrix(exp(B0 + B1*X1 + B2*X2 + B3*X3),nrow=5908,ncol=5)}}
  }
  
 
  num.claims.of.t <-numeric(nrow(Y))
  {for (i in seq(nrow(Y))){
    num.claims.of.t[i] <-sum(Y[i,])}
  }

  num.lambda.of.t<-numeric(nrow(Y))
  {for (i in seq(nrow(Y))){
    num.lambda.of.t[i]<-sum(lambda[i,])}
  }
  
  prod.exp<-1 #numeric(nrow(Y))
  {for (i in seq(nrow(Y))){
    prod.exp[i]<-prod(lambda[i,]^Y[i,]/factorial(Y[i,]))}
  }
  
  
  joint.pdf.mvnb<-(prod.exp)*(gamma(num.claims.of.t + (1/A))/gamma(1/A))*(((1/A)/(num.lambda.of.t + (1/A)))^(1/A))*((num.lambda.of.t + (1/A))^(-num.claims.of.t))
  
  -sum((joint.pdf.mvnb),log=TRUE)
}

start.value <- c(B0=0.01,B1=0.01,B2=0.01,B3=0.01,A=0.01)
MLE_pogam<-mle2(minuslogl=po.gam,start=start.value)
```

But the results

```
Error in as.matrix(exp(B0 + B1 * X1 + B2 * X2 + B3 * X3), nrow = 5908,  : 
  argument "B1" is missing, with no default
```

Please help me how to fix this. thankss!

Comment: Try `start.value <- list(B0=0.01,B1=0.01,B2=0.01,B3=0.01,A=0.01)`. From the docs, start should be a named list, not a named vector

Comment: when I run po.gam(start.value), the ouptut is still
"argument "B1" is missing, with no default"

Comment: That's not how to run the function. `mle2` will fun your function. To test, you'd need `do.call('po.gam', start.value)`

Comment: ok i'll try, thanks for your advice!